# UIImageView disappears after dismissViewControllerAnimated is called

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview

I have a UIView that has a UIImageView. The UIImageView is the complete width and height of my view and it's being used as a background for the view.

In my UIview's view controller I load a new view by calling
`[self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];`

After I finish using this view then the following code is called in my parent view controller.

```
[editorController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

As expected the editor view is removed but the following view's UIImageView that is used as the background completely disappears.

Comment: How are you creating the background view?

Comment: did you have any code in viewDidDisappear?

Comment: I don't have any code in viewDidDisappear. @sbarow As for how I'm creating the background. It's a UIImageView in a xib file that I set the image property on.

Comment: If you are using the `UIImageView` for the sole purpose of setting the _background_, then I suggest you to set the _background_ for your `view` directly, rather than adding a `UIImageView`.

Comment: If you want to stick to the same code, then try calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]` from your `editorController` after you finish using it, rather than calling it from the _parent view_. Check if this helps.